# How to do a POST request using Luvit

Tags: rest, post, lua, luvit

I'm using Luvit for one of my projects which uses some online APIs to make the things simpler. One such API asks me to do a POST request to their endpoint to deal with the data. I looked at their official documentation, and even some unofficial ones, but ended up finding nothing. I even tried some of the following and nothing seems to be working

```lua
local http = require("coro-http")

coroutine.wrap(function()
    local head, body = http.request("POST", JSON_STORE_CLIENT, {{"Content-Type", "application/json"}}, "test")
    print(head)
    print(body)
end)()
--[[
table: 0x7f5f4a732148
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
...
basically tells its a bad request
</html>
]]
```

Can somebody help me in doing REST operations with luvit, especially POST, correctly?

Comment: in your code there are syntax errors: function not closed, headers table not closed, string 'Content-type' must be 'Content-Type'. Can you post minimal code which you tested and not works

Comment: Error is generated for **http response** and not request. Http response generates unknown status code for example: 0 or -1. List of valid status codes you can check in /workspace/wtal-bot/deps/http-codec.lua or https://github.com/luvit/lit/blob/master/deps/http-codec.lua

Comment: @Darius I editted my code a bit and now I got the above response. Now the question is how to do the POST request correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `http.request` works as expected and it returns **response table** (not only headers) and **body string**.

You posting `Content-Type: application/json` but sending invalid data. Body must be valid JSON object:

```lua
local http = require("coro-http")
local json = require("json")

coroutine.wrap(function()
    local data = {param1 = "string1", data = {key = "value"}}
    local res, body = http.request("POST", JSON_STORE_CLIENT,
      {{"Content-Type", "application/json"}},
      json.stringify(data))
      -- or static string [[{"param1": "string1", "data": {"key": "value"}}]]
    print(res.code)
    print(body)
end)()
```